# jQuery Joyride plugin - nothing happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-joyride

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the Joyride plugin for jQuery to work.  I thought it seemed pretty simple, but it's not happening.

I have the following script includes on my page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.joyride-2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/application.js"></script>
```

And all three are loading correctly.  In `application.js` I have called joyride in the following way:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#tour').joyride();
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<ol id="tour">
    <li><p>This is the tour.</p></li>
</ol>
```

For some reason, absolutely nothing is happening when I load the page.  I don't get any errors in the console, literally nothing happens.  Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Aren't you meant to have a `data-id` attribute on the `li` which says the id of the element on which you want the tooltip to appear?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's not necessary - it just pops up as a modal if you leave that out.

Comment: @tfogo - yep, that's correct. Thanks for looking into it though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see anything happen, put the option `autoStart: true` into the joyride function:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#tour').joyride({
        autoStart: true
    });
});
```

[Here's a working plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MgcgzBTTL0ljw97npM9?p=preview)

By the way, if you give your `ol` an id of `joyRideTipContent` that will automatically be set to `display: none` by the CSS.